# Square CollectionView Cell Swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I tried to make two square collectionView cells in one row. I implemented all of the necessary delegates. When the view is loaded, cells are not square but when I start scrolling, some cells are being square.

[image]

when I start scrolling :

[image]

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
   
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

    

    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize{

    let width = (collectionView.frame.width/2)-0.5
    return CGSize(width:width , height: width)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add more margin to width in layout delegate

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize{

    let width = (collectionView.frame.width/2)-10
    return CGSize(width:width , height: width)

}
```

Comment: Hi. Nothing changed

Comment: You would need to implement more delegates: `minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt`, `minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt` and return there `CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude`. Also implement `insetForSectionAt` and return `.zero` and see if you at least get square cells. You can adjust from there.

Comment: Nothing changed